# Django: How do I dynamically filter a dropdown box?

Tags: python, django

Say for example I have a three models. `Content`, `Chapter` and `Page`. Within the `Content` form there will be two dropdown boxes. One for `chapters` and the other for `pages`. If I was to select a `chapter` from the dropdown box, how do I then filter the `page` dropdown box only to show the `pages` within that `chapter`.

models.py

```
class Page(Models.Model):
    # Some details about the page

class Chapter(models.Model):
    # Some detail about the chapter

class Content(models.Model):
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter)
    page = models.ForeignKey(Chapter)
```

views.py

```
def create_contents(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = ContentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/books/all/')
    else:
        form = ContenttForm()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('content/content.html', args)
```

forms.py

```
class ContentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Content
```

Comment: you're going to need to use javascript and do it on the client side

Comment: I developed a solution for this, [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820728/filter-a-drop-down-django-form-element-based-on-a-value-selected-before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you two option:

1. using [django-autocomplete-light](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dependant.html)
2. using jquery like [this](http://www.devinterface.com/blog/en/2011/02/how-to-implement-two-dropdowns-dependent-on-each-other-using-django-and-jquery/)

Comment: Does the `Autocompletes` part go in myapps `admin.py`?. Im having some issues getting it to work. It looks really useful though!!

Comment: yes, you can use `Autocompletes` in your `admin.py`. take a look at [this](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html)