# Filter a Django form select element based on a previously selected element

Tags: django

Let's consider the following models

models.py

```
Class Brand(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class CarModel(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


Class FleetCars(models.Model):
    model_car = models.Foreignkey(CarModel)
```

What is the best way to solve this problem in django?
Suppose a form (for insertions in `FleetCars`) consists of two select elements, like this:

[image: Image example]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<br />Brand:
<select>
   <option value="Brand1">Brand1</option>
   <option value="Brand2">Brand2</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />Model:
<select>
   <option value="Model1_B1">Model1_B1</option>
   <option value="Model1_B2">Model1_B2</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

In this case, I want the options in the second select to depend on the value selected in the first. For example, if the user chose Brand1 for a `Brand` in the first select, the second select would be filtered with only cars whose `Brand` was Brand1, that is, only "Model1_B1".

Obs.
I saw many solutions with `forms.ModelChoiceField`, but only works with edit and since the user do not change the brand.

Comment: there is one application called smart_selects which provide ChainedForeignKey field.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After hours and hours of research, without success, I decided to try to solve on my own. The solution that I found maybe don't be the best or the more elegant, but is working. (For download full Django project, click on this repo => https://github.com/Sidon/djfkf/.)

---

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Brand(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name


class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def brand_name(self):
        return self.brand.company_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Fleet(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def car_name(self):
        return self.car.name

    def brand(self):
        return self.car.brand.company_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

The goal is to register cars on the fleet. The only fields that are will be recorded: Car (foreign key) and description. On the form, there will be one select element for brands that will work just only as a helper for to filter the car's combo box.

---

forms.py

```
import json
from django import forms
from .models import *

class RegCarForm(forms.ModelForm):

    dcars = {}
    list_cars = []
    for car in Car.objects.all():
        if car.brand.company_name in dcars:
            dcars[car.brand.company_name].append(car.name)
        else:
            dcars[car.brand.company_name] = [car.name]
        list_cars.append((car.name,car.name))

    brands = [str(brand) for brand in Brand.objects.all()]

    brand_select = forms.ChoiceField(choices=([(brand, brand) for brand in brands]))
    car_select = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(list_cars))

    brands = json.dumps(brands)
    cars = json.dumps(dcars)

    class Meta:
        model = Fleet
        fields = ('brand_select', 'car_select', 'description',)
```

RegCarForm is a form for register cars, there are three fields: brand_select, car_select, and description. In addition, I defined two JSON attributes: 1) a dictionary whose keys are brands (strings) and values are lists of respective's cars and 2) A list of strings that represent the brands. Those two attributes will work as helpers for JS functions.

---

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import RegCarForm
from .models import *

def regcar(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        car_form = RegCarForm(data=request.POST)

        if car_form.is_valid():
            cdata = car_form.cleaned_data.get
            car_selected = Car.objects.filter(name=cdata('car_select'))
            reg1 = Fleet(car_id=car_selected[0].id, description=cdata('description'))
            reg1.save()
        else:
            print ('Invalid')

    else:
        car_form = RegCarForm()
    return render(request, 'core/regcar.html', {'car_form': car_form})
```

The view is practically auto-explanatory. Assigns the Form to the car_form variable, render the template core/regcar.html and, after Post, make the validation of the form and save the data.

---

regcar.html (template django)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block head %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Registering cars on the fleet. <br />(Populate one drop down based on selection in another)</h1>
    <p>Change the contents of drop down Car based on the selection in dropdown Brand, using Django-forms + Javascritp</p>
    <div class="select-style">
        <form action="." method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ car_form.as_p }}
            <p><input type="submit" value="Register a car"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
    {% include "js1.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

The template only just renders the form and load the script JS. Nothing else.

---

Finally, the js script, that makes the hard work.

```
{% block js %}
    <script language="javascript">
        $('#id_brand_select').change(function() {populateCar(this)});
        $('#id_description').addClass('descriptions');
        cars = {{ car_form.cars | safe }}
        brands = {{ car_form.brands | safe}};
        populateBrand();
        $("#id_car_select").empty();
        $("#id_car_select").append('<option value="" disabled selected>First select a brand</option>');
        function populateBrand() {
            $('#id_brand_select').empty();
            $("#id_brand_select").append('<option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>');
            $.each(brands, function(v) {
                $('#id_brand_select')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", brands[v])
                    .text(brands[v]));
            });
        }

        function populateCar(event) {
            brand = $("#id_brand_select option:selected").text();
            $("#id_car_select").empty();
            $("#id_car_select").append('<option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>');
            for (let [b, bcars] of Object.entries(cars)) {
                if (b == brand) {
                    //alert(b);
                    for (car in bcars) {
                        $('#id_car_select')
                            .append($("<option></option>")
                                .attr("value", bcars[car])
                                .text(bcars[car]));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

When the document is loaded, this script assigns the change event of brand_select (combo for selection of brand) to the function poplulateCar, assign the form's JASON attributes (cars and brands) to a JS variables and call the populateBrand function.

### Links:

Full project in Django:
https://github.com/Sidon/djfkf/

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using the form?

Comment: Yes, but you can use the form only for create the jsons.

Comment: If you don't need the form, create the json in the view.

Comment: I need dynamic select box as you had done, But not using form, I'm using this for get method. Could you please elaborate more about select box without form or some other method to achieve this

Comment: Just move the code that create the json from forms.py to view.py.

Comment: This answer was highly applicable to my situation, and helped a lot. Just wanted to point out to others that there are different ways to transfer the JSON values from the form to the JS block, like with Ajax. For me, dumping did not work—due to syntax errors in the JS.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Country(models.Model):
   country_name=models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

class State(models.Model):
   state_name=models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

class MyCustomModal(models.Model):
   country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
   state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Here is my Form

```
class MyCustomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyCustomModal
        fields = [
            'country',
            'state',           
        ]        

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyCustomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)        
        self.fields['country'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('1','india'),('2','US')])
        self.fields['state'].queryset = State.objects.filter(pk=2)
```

Comment: this will work only initially in the init, it will not change after selection