# How to get the selected value from html select with django

Tags: python, html, django

I would like to know if it's possible to get the selected value from a select HTML without using a `submit` input? Because when I hit the submit, the value selected is returned but it reloads the web page and the select goes back to it's intial state.

Here is my code to visualize better:

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    id_desi = request.POST.get('drop_desi')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'designation_liste': df.designation_liste})
```

**index.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'DataMat-index' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <select name="drop_desi">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select value -- </option>
        {% for i in designation_liste %}
        <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="valider">
</form>
```

Comment: You can use jquery

Comment: Yes I tried to look up, do you have some examples by any chances?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? You can't retrieve the value of the form with django without submitting the form. If you want to do something directly on the client side (the browser), you would need to use some javascript of some sort. Without knowing your intentions, we can't really point out a solution.

Comment: Yes I didn't give enough info. What I want to do is to make dependent dropwdowns.  When I get the selected value from the first one I can update the second and so on. But with my code to get the selected value, I have to submit the form and so to refresh my page and with that the first dropdown goes back to its initial state. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Hey, did you end up solving this problem of dependent dropdowns? It's exactly what I'm trying to tackle right now in Django.

Comment: I found this other answer helpful in rendering select options based on another select's .change() method with JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43074402/13368695